# Как влияет на оптимальность выборки FETCH FIRST?

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация

Есть таблица. Предполагается наличие уникальной записи по выборке (см. ниже). Цель - извлечь данные за минимальное время.

Если запрос с `FETCH FIRST` находит первую соответствующую запись, возвращает ли он результат? Или в любом случае проходит по всей таблице и возвращает указанное количество строк (может, еще и сортирует)?

Что будет работать быстрее? На каких условиях? Есть ли в диалекте Oracle команда, чтобы вытаскивать первую попавшуюся запись без прохода по всей таблице?

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOME_TABLE 
WHERE FIRST_ID IS NULL AND SECOND_ID=200 AND THIRD_ID=300
```

или

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOME_TABLE 
WHERE FIRST_ID IS NULL AND SECOND_ID=200 AND THIRD_ID=300 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Посмотрите планы обоих запросов. PS. Нужно минимальное время - создайте индекс по полям отбора. *Есть ли в диалекте oracle команда, чтобы вытаскивать первую попавшуюся запись без прохода по всей таблице?* По-моему, ни в одном диалекте нет такой команды.

Comment: Оптимизатор самостоятельно принимает решение по каждому запросу. Если например он увидит что вы задали условие из уникального индекса, то во первых он скорее всего пойдет по нему, во вторых будет точно знать что записей больше нет и остановится после выбора первой. Если индекса нет и нет доп указаний вроде fetch first или условия rownum=1 в where, то oracle в любом случае должен будет убедиться что подходящих по условию записей больше не осталось и пойдет сканировать дальше

Comment: id в запросе вторичные, указывают на запись в других таблицах. т.е. индексированные. Если у нас 1млрд записей и первая запись - нужная? Мы всё равно все записи прогоняем?

Comment: _указывают на запись в других таблицах. т.е. индексированны_, одно с другим не связано. Почему вы не дали в вопросе структуру таблицы? Вы не знаете как, или есть другие причины?

Comment: Из соображений конфиденциальности. Нехорошо рабочие моменты выкладывать) Есть ли разница? Вроде как информации достаточно. Отбирает ли fetch first первые встречные записи и прекращает работу или прогоняет все записи? Делал тестовые запросы - у меня реально быстрее получалось. Но коллега говорит, что это не так работает (объяснить, правда, не может). В официальной документации смутно, но вроде как тоже намек на полный прогон записей. Может кто-нибудь нормально объяснить?

Comment: О каких соображениях конфиденциальности идёт речь? Какие тайны содержит команда `create table` с надуманными именами таблицы и столбцов?

Comment: Структура таблицы большая. Порядка 25 полей с кучей вторичных ключей, ограничений. "Тайну", конечно, вряд ли открыть, но под условия конфиденциальности такая выкладка попасть может. Видоизменять столько текста посчитал ненужным, тем более что в следующем ответе вы всё поняли правильно: id записи (условно главный) в выборке не используется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Какой выбор оптимальнее?

Этот выбор делает оптимизатор запросов. Он может составить несколько планов выполнения,  сравнить их предпологаемые затраты и выбрать оптимальный.

При составлени запроса в первую очередь следует уделить внимание тому, чтобы он соответствовал условию задачи. Так как, условие задачи в вопросе: *Предполагается наличие уникальной записи по выборке*, а оба запроса из вопроса выполняют разные задачи, то и сравнивать их эффективность бесполезно.

Первый запрос предпологает наличие уникального индекса по всем условиям выборки, то есть:

```
create table t1 (id1 int, id2 int, id3 int, constraint uqt1 unique (id1,id2,id3));
```

В этом случае, будет читаться индекс - обычно не более 3-4 блоков, по найденной записи в индексе прочтётся один блок таблицы. На этом поиск записи закончится.

Во втором запросе по видимому, идет поиск одной записи без уникального индекса (иначе `FETCH FIRST` не имеет смысла). В этом случае, сканирование таблицы (или диапазона нормального индекса при его наличии) будет продолжатся до того, пока первая запись, удовлетворяющая условию выборки, не будет найдена. На этом дальнейшее сканирование будет прервано.

Comment: Всё верно. id записи не используется. Я, наверно, ошибся: не существует индекса на эти 3 поля. Это вторичные id. Думал, что если они id - то в своих таблицах они индексированы (чисто по столбцу id) по умолчанию и это используется как-то в этой выборке.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю - данные будут считаться блоками. И fetch first все-таки остановится при первой найденной записи? Тогда как без него будет полный проход по записям?

Comment: Как можно провести корректную проверку на сравнение скоростей выполнения команд? Чтобы нивелировать влияние канала связи, внутренних оптимизационных операций бд (подозреваю, что она может кэшировать, индексировать и т.п. самостоятельно)

Comment: Да, вы правильно понимаете. Данные всегда считываются блоками, это наименьшая единица хранения. При fetch first движок SQL остановит чтение, но только в том случае, если запрос не сортирован, что в свою очередь, довольно редкая операция.

Comment: Самое простое - сравнить в SQL*Plus: `SQL> set autotrace traceonly`.  Надо будет конечно разобраться с отдельными значениями статистики, чтобы правильно интерпретировать их при сравнении.

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснения